# CodeIgniter using Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I cant find error when i click on a button nothing happens, i dont get any error in console, very is error maybe in data field?

I have ajax part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#brisanje').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost/test2/home/ajax',
            type: 'Post',
            data: form_data,
            success: function() {
                alert("paun");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

button

```
<button type="submit"  id="brisanje" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Obriši sliku</button>
```

and controler

```
 public function ajax(){
     redirect('home/login');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this way in your `ajax` function ,

`url : <?php echo base_url(). 'home/ajax' ; ?>,
type : POST,`

Comment: I think here you might consider `<?php echo base_url('home/ajax'); ?>` instead

Comment: Agreed . It's even better.

Comment: use this `redirect(base_url('home/login'))` in your ajax function

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Redirecting in the `ajax()` function caused the problem. I'll leave my junk here anyway, but since I got the checkmark I best provide the actual answer!

---

This doesn't seem to solve the problem, but I'll leave it here for now anyway

---

It looks like you're missing the "Action" part of your controller action. You probably are getting a 404 error, although I can't remember exactly what happens when CI cannot find the controller action. Maybe its a 403 error.

Anyway, try naming your `ajax` function `ajaxAction` and see if that works. A way to test this would be to browse directly to the url `http://localhost/home/ajax` (bypass the actual ajax) and you should see any errors that occur.

If you're using a browser with a debugger (most of them, push F12 and see what you get), you should also be able to see the ajax request firing in the console or network tab, and then you can inspect the response for errors.

Comment: I try that already i can load function ajax from my controler its ajax part problem i cant figure  it out, ajax wont load function in my controller

Comment: I assume English is not your first language so no worries there, but I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can you browse to `http://localhost/home/ajax`? If so, what do you see?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, yes its ok http://localhost/home/ajax when i type in url , but when i click on button ajax request dont work, it should be run http://localhost/home/ajax but nothing happens

Comment: Okay then my initial idea was wrong -- the only thing I can think of now is that the ajax isn't even being fired. You can add an alert before `$.ajax` to test this, otherwise I'm stumped, sorry!

Comment: Sory mr maniac i think i find error could you confrm it i didnt put anything in form_open() now i change it to form_open('home/ajax'), but i dont get success Alert anyway?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you're trying to do a redirect in the controller? Try removing the redirect and echoing out a string and then alert that in the ajax. That's an easy way to test that you're actually sending info to the controller.

Comment: @user3776880 `form_open` is just a shortcut function that sets up your `<form>` tag. That shouldn't effect anything. The other user "C A" probably has the right idea -- the redirect might be causing the issue.

Comment: Problem is that ajax code must be on view page in <script> tags i order to work, and not loaded from 1.js file